# any tips for viewing list of tags to the user

Tags: php, laravel, view, tags

I'm working on clothes store app ...

- each company can create ... categories (like ... shirts , pants , jackets ...etc).

and each category have(multi items ) and the company can inset any tag its want to add .

***hint : every thing is dynamic (categories , items , tags) for each company .***

**my questions :** how to view clothes to the and filtering clothes based on the entries tags !!

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood

These are your models

```
class Tag
{
  public function categories()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
  }
}

class Category
{
  public function tags()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
  }
  public function items()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
  }
}

class Item
{
  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
  }
}
```

And this is how you can get all **Items/Clothes** by a single Tag...

In your routes, add a route like

```
Route::get('items/tags/{id}', 'ItemController@getByTagId')->name('items.tag.get');
```

Then in your `ItemContoller`, you add a function like this

```
public function getByTagId($id)
{
  $items = Item::whereHas('category.tags', function($query) use ($id) {
                $query->where('id', $id);
              })
              ->paginate(20);

  return view('items.tags', compact('items'));
}
```